# How to convert vector of DER encoded string to x509 in openSSL

Tags: android, c++, string, vector

```
SfNetworkLibrary::VerifyResult SfNetworkLibrary::VerifyX509CertChain(
    const std::vector<std::string>& cert_chain,
    const std::string& hostname,
    const std::string& auth_type) {
```

In this above code of Android Jelly bean 4.2.2 for server authentication.
I need to convert this **DER encoded string** `std::vector<std::string> cert_chain` to **X509** format.

I want to do this conversion , so that I can set this server certificate on openssl. 
`SSL_CTX_use_certificate(ctx,x)` where `ctx` is the context and `x` is x509 certificate.

Can I use `d2i_x509` to convert DER encoded string to x509??

But in this case , we have vector of strings `vector<string>&cert_chain`, So how do I convert it??

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call d2i_x509() on all certificates in cert_chain verctor. If that is the case, for each element in the vector, convert string to c string (char *) say cstr. Use string::c_str() to get the c string (say cstr). Now call  d2i_x509(NULL,&cstr,strlen(cstr)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Pallavi,Thanks for the reply.Is there a way to convert the entire cert_chain to x509 format???

Comment: Does that make sense? Each string in cert_chain correspond to a different X509. Right? If yes, how can you get single X509 from all strings of cert_chain?